# Поиск внутри блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

есть блок со списком

```
<ul class="list">
<li class="nored">
<div class="foto"><img></div>
<span class="fio">Алексей</span>
</li>

<li class="nored">
<div class="foto"><img></div>
<span class="fio">Алексей</span>
</li>

<li class="nored">
<div class="foto"><img></div>
<span class="fio">Алексей</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

как можно организовать поиск по этому списку по имени ?

Comment: Вообще непонятно.

Comment: Вам нужен поиск по содержимому .fio?

Comment: да по fio  я так понял через аякс вроде

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вот поиск li элемента по содержимому .fio:

```js
var name = 'Алексей';
var el = $('.list>li>.fio:contains("' + name + '")').parent();
console.log(el.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
 <li class="nored">
  <div class="foto"><img></div>
  <span class="fio">Алексей</span>
 </li>
 
 <li class="nored">
  <div class="foto"><img></div>
  <span class="fio">Алексей</span>
 </li>
 
 <li class="nored">
  <div class="foto"><img></div>
  <span class="fio">Алексей</span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо решил с помощью jquery.quicksearch.js
 <script>
   $(function () {
    /*
    Example 1
    */
    $('input#id_search').quicksearch('ul.list li');
    
    
   });
  </script>